# RESTful route structure for FindFirstByAttribute

Tags: rest

Designing a REST API for a resource item that has its id, and also has a non-unique reference number. One of the most typical queries of this API will be something like

```
FindFirstByReference(referenceNumber)
FindLastByReference(referenceNumber)
```

Each of these returns a single item, not an array of one item.

I am thinking how this can best translate into REST.

(1) The first option is to list all the items, filtered by the reference and with an additional attribute of `return_one` (that can be the `first` or the `last` of the list)

```
GET /items?reference=123&return_one=first
```

The problem with this approach that changing the *shape* of the response because of the presence or not of the attribute `return_one` feels wrong.

(2) A second option is to select a sub-resource of the items array returned by the query.

```
GET /items?reference=123/first
```

(3) A third option is to use the reference attribute as an id in order to select just one.

```
GET /items/reference=123&return_one=first
```

This can be confusing as the difference between (1) and (3) is just one character.

Do any of these options seems OK? Is there another option that I should consider? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s better not to have an API which can give either a list or a single object. In your case, it can be `/items` to get a list of item resources. Whereas when you want to limit it to a single resource or a limited number it can be done using a `limit` parameter. So it will be an array of items even if the limit is 1, so as the uniformity is maintained. Also you can apply another query parameter `sort_by` using which you can sort based on any fields.

Sample `/items?limit=1&sort_by=+id`

Note : for sort_by, you can define + for ascending and - for descending order